# freemarker configuration in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

I am using freemarker 2.3.21 with struts 2.3.24, I need to configure (customize) freemarker for the struts.

**Why ?**

Because in FTL file I need to change the default number formatting to **" computer"** format

**Problem**

Numbers are printing with default formatting, for example, 12345 will print in FTL file as 12,345 so this number becomes a string when I need to re-use it.

**Basic Solution** 
I set the number formatting in the java program and test the solution that is working properly and this solution will work for that ftl which are processed with below object.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_21);
        cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(FTLUtility.class, ftlRootUrl);
        cfg.setNumberFormat("computer"); // this will show the number without formatting
```

But in case of struts, it's using other configuration which I don't know where that configuration exists. I need to customize that one.

I know that we can use **${someNumverVar?c}** that will resolve my problem but I don't want to replace each variable like this.

if you have any idea or suggestion please feel free to share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Struts documentation, you can specify the FreeMarker configuration settings with the `freemarker.properties` file, which should be "in the classpath". (The list of the settings can be found [in the FreeMarker API docs of Configuration.setSetting](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setSetting-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-))

BTW, don't use 2.3.21; that's a very old version. (I don't mean the `incompatibleImprovements`, but the version of the jar.)

Comment: freeemarker version is not a problem...I m using that for a specific reason...including freemarker.properties in classpath resolve the problem :P